# Visual Studio 2010: How to enforce build order of projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, build

I had no problem with this in Visual Studio 2008 but it seems that VS 2010 is having an issue, and I'm betting it's probably me.

I have a solution with an ASP.NET Web Site Project and a few C# projects (BLL, DAL, Tests in NUnit). I have configured the build process for the test project to automatically run NUnit to run the tests. I would like to ensure that the BLL and DAL projects build before the test project so that the tests will run against the latest compiled version (yes, I know I could do this all in one project, but I'm choosing not to -- please bear with me :) )

So, I set the dependencies of the Test project to include the BLL, DAL, and Web Application projects, and the build order shows BLL, DAL, Web Application, and then Tests. However, I noticed that the BLL doesn't actually build when I build the Test project.

Any idea what this could be or any option I might be missing to force the other projects to build when I build the Test project?

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx

Comment: If the solution configuration that you're building, is build checked for your BLL project?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Nick Craver mentioned checking the Configuration Manager to ensure you have the project selected to build for a given configuration.

However, to set the build order for multiple projects in a solution right click the solution and choose "Project Build Order..." from the context menu.

Comment: I tried this, but don't see how to affect the order. The note says "Use the Dependencies tab to change the build order", but the other tab only has checkboxes.

Comment: You make the project that you want to build first a dependency of the one you want to build last.

Comment: Then check the other tab to make sure it all worked out for you.

Comment: The "build" checkbox was correct for me. I had answered and accepted the answer but then it was deleted, I think due to me saying "thanks". Therefore I'll mark this answer as the correct answer.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948807/1143274) for screenshots of all this.

Answer (score 21):

I'll expound upon my comment a bit here, for those having a similar issue.

Open up the configuration manager by right clicking on the solution and choosing **Configuration Manager**, then make sure build is checked for the appropriate project (for your current configuration) in the right-hand column here:

[image: Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 18):

Maybe instead of setting order manually you could use [Project Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx) which allows you to specify build order indirectly.

> 1. In Solution Explorer, select a project.
> 2. On the Project menu, choose Project Dependencies. The Project Dependencies dialog box opens.
>      **The Project Dependencies option is only available in a solution with more than one project.**
> 3. On the Dependencies tab, select a project from the Project drop-down menu.
> 4. In the Depends on field, select the check box of any other project that must build before this project does.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the issue happening in my VS2012, I did the following:

Right click Project Properties --> Common Properties --> Framework and References

Now you will find some projects shown on the Dependence Tab are missing in the "References" list.

Click "Add New Reference" to add the missing the projects.