# Errors while building projects in MS VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, hyperlink, compiler-errors

I have a .sln file with more than 30 .vcprojs under it. When I build my solution for the first time, I get a lot of link errors. However, if I repeat this operation - cleaning the project and then rebuilding it - the errors disappear. Why does this happen? Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if some of the projects are dependent on others and the build order is incorrect.  There are some answers to this on SO here: [Visual Studio 2010: How to enforce build order of projects in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653973/484072)