# Microsoft.CppClean.targets deletes files I need

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rebuild

I have a VS2012 solution. One of the Project A generates a .h file at runtime. This header file is used by another Project B. Project A and Project B are in the same directory.

However when Project B starts rebuild, C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppClean.targets deletes the files generated by Project A. Due to this Project B cannot find the file anymore and build fails.

How can I avoid the files being deleted during a clean build? Should the two projects be moved to a different directory?

Note that this problem does not occur in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the [build order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653973/visual-studio-2010-how-to-enforce-build-order-of-projects-in-a-solution) in the solution? It has to be explicitly set that project B depends on A, unless you use the [project referencing functionality built into VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx) to directly set the dependency between the two projects.

Comment: Yes, the project dependencies are correctly set. Project A builds first and generates files at runtime. When Project B start a build it deletes these files although the files are nneded for project B to build.

Comment: @YonatanSimson then ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Is this header generated in the temp ("Intermediate") directory by a "Build Event"? If so, then Project B assumes it's a temp file and deletes it. This is because project B's cleanup finds the header in the temp directory but doesn't know that it's an output of Project A. Possible solutions:

- Separate the output folder from the temp folder and generate the header in the output folder.
- Keep the output and temp folders together but separate the output/temp folder of Project A from that of Project B.
- Generate the header in a Custom Build Step instead of a Build Event, and specify the header as the Output of the step.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue while migrating to VS 2015. The solution is to set the "Configuration Property->General->Intermediate Directory" to ..\\$(ProjectName)\ so that Build.CppClean doesn't clean up previous build dlls from other unrelated projects. This worked for me.