# How does one specify which files get deleted in the CPPClean task?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compilation

I am having trouble when trying to compile two projects. Project A depends on Project B. However Project A deletes files that are created by Project B. The deleted files can be seen A.CppClean.log. Then the rebuild falls on link errors.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

This problem has been asked in the following places with no answer:

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018634/microsoft-cppclean-targets-deletes-files-i-need/30015947#30015947)

[Visual Studio Social Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f72df9a-88c7-4dc5-8acf-250bbd54e5f2/unwanted-deletion-of-sibling-project-files?forum=vcgeneral)