# VS2017-Build fails because compiler don't wait until previous project dlls is generated

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, dependencies

I have a solution with 11 projects with cross dependecies. Let's say I've p1 and p2, p2 needs the p1 dll to build. All projects have their compilation output path changed.

So, when I don't have the DLLs generated and I click Build Solution the compiler starts building all the projects in the correct order, but they fail because the compiler do not find the previous project DLL. The DLLs, in fact, are builded correctly, and if I make another build it works perfectly. But this first time it fails.

The compilation order is correct, the DLLs get generated and the second time I build it works... Someone have any ideas why it fails the first time?

EDIT: I want to remark that my compilation order is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010: How to enforce build order of projects in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653973/visual-studio-2010-how-to-enforce-build-order-of-projects-in-a-solution)

Comment: No, it's not uplicated, my solution's compilation order is fine.

Comment: Are you on the absolute latest version (15.9.2 as we speak)? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes