# Adding Packages for Google Mobile Ads support in Xamarin.iOS Causes Linking Errors

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, admob

I am adding Google Mobile Ads support to a Xamarin.iOS app.  I added the following packages (Essentials was already present and building fine).  MobileAds requires the Firebase Core and Xamarin.Build.Download packages.

[image: packages in my project]

When I build my project I get a number of linking errors such as

```
...Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GULIsLoggableLevel. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210) (iPhoneSkeleton)
```

Any specific ideas on where to get the package/library/reference to resolve this specific error?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/303 Seems to be an issue with versioning? Do you have the latest version of all the packages? Or try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143423/11104068

Comment: @Saamer, your stackoverflow reference was useful.  It worked.  I performed a Clean All in VS for Mac and then manually deleted everything under the project bin and obj folders.  A subsequent build worked and I have been in good shape since.  

FWIW the github reference was not applicable as this was not a versioning issue; all the versioning prereqs were met as of the original post state.

Many thanks!

Comment: Alright I put it in as an answer below. Let me know if it looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BillNeedels mentioned, he was able to fix this by simply doing a Clean All and then deleting all the bin and obj folders, as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143423/11104068) and it started working in the subsequent build!